# android Firestore document cannot delete array child

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

please find attached my documents array structure:
[Structure of my documents arry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvHI4.png)

I try to delete this entry using this code, but unfortunately it doesnt work:

```
      Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();
            Map<String, Object> deleteObject = new HashMap<>();

            deleteObject.put("chatId", users.get(position).getChatId());
            deleteObject.put("contactId", users.get(position).getId());
            deleteObject.put("isGroup", users.get(position).isGroup());
            deleteObject.put("isRead", users.get(position).isRead());
            deleteObject.put("lastMsg", users.get(position).getLastMsg());
            deleteObject.put("lastMsgTs", users.get(position).getLastMsgTs());
            deleteObject.put("sentBy", users.get(position).getSentBy());
            deleteObject.put("active", false);
            docData.put("openChats", FieldValue.arrayUnion(deleteObject));

            db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .set(docData, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Unable to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

I cannot see any error and also the onSuccess gets called. Does someone know how i can one map entry without using arrays position

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to delete.  The code here is only every going to add or replace fields in a document.

Comment: i want to delete the whole entry in openChats

Comment: but if openChats has more than just one entry it should only delete the selected entry

Comment: I think you would want to use FieldValue.arrayRemove instead of FieldValue.arrayUnion.

Comment: yes but it doesnt work as well

Comment: Can you show current data and updated code ?